# Javascript - Given width, height and space constraint, and allow rotation, calculate how many rectangle will fit in a big rectangle

Tags: javascript, logic

I'm constructing a function, which need to pass in 5 parameters:

```
1 - height of small rectangle
2 - width of small rectangle
3 - height of big rectangle
4 - width of big rectangle
5 - minimum space between each small rectangle
```

all the parameter above are number, measure in mm

and it will return object like:

```
{
  numOfSmallRect: x,
  remainArea: y
}
```

Remaining space would be simply `bigRectArea - (num * smallRectArea)`

But I have no idea how to get the `num`

What I have tried is `bigReactArea % smallRectArea`, but actually it's not valid, since if smallRect is `100*2` and bigRect is `50*50`, the result will be larger than 0, but it's impossible to fit `100*2` in `50*50`

Comment: are 2 and 4 the same thing? are 1,2,3 and 4 four different rectangles? what is `number`?

Comment: thanks for your advise, I have improve the question description
1,2 are same rectangle, aka the small rectangle, 3,4 are same rectangle,

Comment: This is a hard problem which is discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99796/given-the-dimensions-of-two-rectangles-find-how-many-smaller-rectangles-fit-the - this page has a link to a lengthy paper that proposes a solution.